# Iterator for 2 separated data structures

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

i've a graph class which has two std::map in it; the maps are private, and i want the user to only be able to loop through both maps, not modifying them.

The point is, (well the first point is i never wrote a standard iterator) they have to look like there's only one map from outside.

so that a code that looks like:

```
for (auto element : stuff)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
```

will actually do that:

```
for (auto element : map_1)
    {
    }
for (auto element : map_2)
    {
    }
```

How do i manage the step between the first map and the second one?

Comment: Sure, make your own iterator and once you reach `map_1.end()` set it to `map_2.begin()` and make your end iterator just `map_2.end()`

Comment: oh when the solution is in front of your eyes and you didnt think of it… thanks!

Comment: @NathanOliver You must whether the iterator points to `map_1` in order to know if it's well defined to compare with `map_1.end()`, so it isn't quite as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your custom iterator, store two fields:

```
struct example {
    unsigned map_index;
    map_iterator it;
};
```

`map_index` tells you which map is being iterated.

In the increment operator after incrementing `it`, if `it == map_0.end()` (I changed the numbering to start from zero) then increment `map_index` and set `it` to `map_1.begin()`.

Use `{map_1.end(), 1}` as the end iterator.

In the comparison operators, compare `map_index` first and only compare `it` if the indices match.

---

That said, you can save yourself a lot of work by using existing, generic functionality: [boost::range::join](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/join.html)

Comment: i prefer to limit myself to std libraries for now, but thanks for the advice, now i'll just have to throw myself into standard iterators world